# Access more options via Gnome Power Manager

Tags: 11.10, power-management

im running Ubuntu 11.10 & am using the Gnome interface. I have installed the Gnome power manager and I am assuming this is it:

[image]

This doesn't have that many options. I've seem some screen shots of the power manager and they seem to show the gnome power manager with alot of the options I want to have control over. So my over question is this: is this the gnome power manager & if it is, then how can I access more options?

Edit:

the other screen shot I am referring to is the one available when viewing the gnome power manager via Synaptic, or even something like this

[image]

Comment: Can you add some links to the screenshots you have been looking at.  thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I have the ability to 'bump' this question, but the other screen shot I am referring to is the one available when viewing the gnome power manager via Synaptic, or even something like this http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/stable/figures/gpm-prefs-battery.png.en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second screenshot you have referred to is the "old" Gnome-2 style Power Manager screen.

The Gnome-3 developers took a close look at the various Gnome applications and re-wrote and/or redesigned many applications.

The various applets that made up the Gnome-2 control panel were brought together under the System Settings *gnome-control-center* application.  It was this move that has resulted in the *simplification* of the power-management screen.

Many of the Gnome-2 power-management options you were familiar with are still available - but have been tucked away in either *gconf-editor* or *dconf-editor*

**gconf-editor**

[image]

Navigate to *apps.gnome_settings_daemon.plugins*

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type *gconf-editor* to launch this application.

**dconf-editor**

[image]

Navigate to *org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power*

Install [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) and use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type *dconf-editor* to launch this application

Comment: Thank you fossfreedom, using your walkthrough I was able to find the hidden options using dconf editor.