# How to access gnome-power-manager in Lubuntu?

Tags: indicator, lubuntu, power-management, gnome-power-manager, location

I have decided to replace Xfce4-power-manager with gnome-power-manager in Lubuntu 12.04 (didn't knew how to disable the tray icon in fact), which I did using synaptic, and now it shows:

[image]

But `gnome-power-manager` is nowhere to be found.
Searching for the file, I only see this:

[image]

There is only `/usr/bin/gnome-power-statistics`

Shouldn't be a `gnome-power-manager` executable and with options that should look like in [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/109487/47206) question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gnome-power-manager` was a daemon and an executable on gdm. The `gnome-power-manager` binary is gone and the functionality was moved into `gnome-settings-daemon`.

---

Edit since I [found a source here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2011-July/msg09121.html).

Comment: thnx, tried `gnome-settings-daemon` it would not work properly in lxde, opening it provided only keyboard layout settings and massed up my lxpanel, so i'm back to xfce4-power-manager

Comment: The only thing I know is that Lubuntu use the xfce4-power-manager, for some reason there is not one for LXDE.